# NGINX redirect index.php UNLESS url contains /admin/

Tags: magento, url, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to remove index.php from the URL without breaking the Magento admin panel.  We're attempting to reduce SEO "duplicate content", so we are looking to do a 301 redirect if the url contains index.php... unless it is in the admin area.

Examples:

(domain)/index.php -> redirect to (domain)

(domain)/index.php/category-one/ -> (domain)/category-one/

(domain)/index.php/admin/report -> DO NOT REDIRECT

I have this working except the /admin/ bit

```
if ($request_uri ~ .*.index\.php(.*)) {
    return 301 $1;  
    }
```

NGINX does not allow for nested `IF` statements.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil), so consider using rewrite:

```
rewrite /index\.php(?:$|/((?!admin(?:/|$)).*)) /$1 permanent;
```

It will remove index.php except when it's followed by /admin, but only when "admin" is at the end of the url or followed by a /. The regex is a bit bloated, but it will do the right thing and redirect on words like "administer" and won't introduce any extra slashes into the url.

Comment: Rewrite has the problem to only deal with the path, doesn't it? So query parameters are missing in your suggested answer. Still "If is Evil" is correct, thought.